# Limitations of algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working with data set with highest value of 7 and lowest value of $-5$
I found the range-$$7-(-5)=12$$

Now let's say that each element of my data set is decreased by 2.

It would not affect  which observation is the highest and lowest.

Let observation no. $a$ be the highest observation and observation no.$b$ be the lowest observation after subtracting 2 from every element still observation no. $a$ will be the highest and observation no.$b$ will be the lowest.

Then,

Let highest observation=$x$

Let lowest observation=$y$

After subtracting 2 from every
element, the range would be:-

$$x-2-y-2=x-y-4$$

Right?

So I substitute the value to:-

$x=7$

$y=-5$

Substituting in the formula:-

$$range=7-(-5)-4=8$$

But if I do it without algebra:-

$$range=(7-2)-(-5-2)=5-(-7)=12$$

We see two different solutions but both should have been equal off course the arthimetic solution is the one which looks more sure and correct.

But if it is correct, Is algebra wrong?

Is it where algebra loses, it's power?

Or I have done some mistake?

Or Arthimetic is wrong?(Which can't be according to me,because algebra and whole mathematics is based on it.)

Comment: $$
(x-2)-(y-2)=x-2-y+2=x-y
$$

Comment: Okay, I have got that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made a mistake here

> $x-2-y-2=x-y-4$

It should be  $$(x-2) -(y-2) = (x-2) - y + 2 = x-y$$

Comment: (+1) You were too fast for me. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Oh, yes you are write.